# Repeting pattern in Regex - Javascript

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to match a pattern in regex that simulate a nested tree with words separated by dots, and leaf node separated by "->" or not.

It should start with "$".

words should be formed by \w{1,32} only

I'm using javascript

ex:

```
$any.number.of.words.followed.by.dot.and.final.word.followed.by.arrow.or->not

$root.f1.f2->col4 -OK (complete)

$f4.folder7 -OK (do not have the leaf node)

$f1->col7 -OK (just root and leaf node)

$root.g5.tt.dd...bbh.hht.sdwswsw->col7 -NOK ("..." is wrong)

$.ferf->45 -NOK (words should have at least one \w)

$$e.fe.45 - NOK (starts with $$)

$feefefefefefefefe -NOK (should have at least one "." or "->"
```

My goal is to have 2 patterns, one that includes leaf node (->), and one without it

without leaf node: `/\$[\w+\.]+/`

with leaf node: `/\$[\w+\.]+->\w+/`

It works for the most of the cases, but it fails to identify NOK examples above.

My real question is how I define a short pattern to repeat using quantifiers ? when I use quantifiers, it always consider repetition of the last symbol
How to find repetition for the following pattern ? `\w{1,32}.\{1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single pattern for both variations, you can optionally repeat the dots and the word chars, and optionally match the `->` and word chars, or match only the `->` part

```
^\$\w{1,32}(?:(?:\.\w{1,32})+(?:->\w{1,32})?|->\w{1,32})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\$\w{1,32}` Match `$` and 1-32 word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\.\w{1,32})+` Match 1+ repetitions of `.` and 1 - 32 word chars
  - `(?:->\w{1,32})?` Optionally match `->` and word chars
  - `|` Or
  - `->\w{1,32}` Match `->` and word chars
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7s7qHA/1)

A separate pattern without a leaf node, where there are 1+ repetitions of a dot and word characters till the end of string

```
^\$\w{1,32}(?:\.\w{1,32})+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uagPgn/1)

A separate pattern with a leaf node, where there are optional repetitions of a dot and word characters and a mandatory `->` part:

```
^\$\w{1,32}(?:\.\w{1,32})*->\w{1,32}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s3mxab/1)

Comment: It works, thanks. how would be the two separate patterns for with or without leaf node ?

Comment: @RodrigoBelli I have added also 2 separate patterns.

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird...
The only issue I'm having now, is that I'm using Chevrotain parser lib, and it doesn't allow use of anchors such as ^ and $. The anchor ^ doesn't seems to be a problem, but without the anchor $ the solution doesn't seems to work =(

Comment: @RodrigoBelli Can you try it like this? https://regex101.com/r/dCII18/1 and https://regex101.com/r/E0uPL7/1

Comment: It works Good! =D